# How to use pairs.panel for only certain rows in the dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a correlation panel using only specific rows. I am using the native R dataframe "iris" and want to create three correlation panels that relate only to particular species. This is my code:

```
library(psych)
pairs.panels(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",], lm=TRUE)
pairs.panels(iris[iris$Species == "versicolor",], lm=TRUE)
pairs.panels(iris[iris$Species == "virginica",], lm=TRUE)
```

Although I am getting a correlation panel for each specie separately, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 'a' and 'b' must be finite
```

This is the error that appears on the correlation panel output (pls see link): 
[error on panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUjed.png)

I already tried creating different dataframes that only contain the specific rows that I want. For example:

```
setosa <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]
pairs.panels(setosa, lm=TRUE)
```

But I still get the same error.

Would appreciate any help to try and get rid of the error.

Comment: The last column contains the species name and may be omitted if you filter on species, so: `pairs.panels(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", 1:4], lm=TRUE)` may be what you want for *setosa*

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the factor to give colors to scatterplot, as in the example

```
pairs.panels(iris[, c(1:4)], #never include factors in corr matrix
             bg=c("blue4","pink",'darkgreen')[iris$Species],#use factor to give colors to scatterplots
             pch=21,
             lm=TRUE, 
             method='kendall')
```

[image: corr matrix with factor]